# android <uses-sdk> does not update

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk

Using Eclipse, I was using android:minSdkVersion="10", got the error message that this was too low, and updated it to 18. After cleaning the project, refreshing and building Android Environment, I still get the same error message!

In Properties -> Android -> Project Build Target, I have selected Android 4.4.2, with an API level of 19.

in AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="18" android:targetSdkVersion="19"/>
```

ERROR:

"Call requires API level 17(current min is10):android.app.AlertDialog.Builder#setOnDismissListener"

How do I make sure my update in AndroidManifest really works?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Clean the project. If that doesn't work then restart Eclipse.

Answer (score 0):

It has been a while since I've used Eclipse for Android development. If you're new to Android, I'd highly recommend that you check out Android Studio, instead.

Anyway, this sounds like a build issue. I'm imagining that you're using the default ant build script so in that case the most likely culprit is your project properties file.

Look for a file called "project.properties"

and add/modify a line to contain the following:

```
# Project target
target=android-18
```

It sounds like it's currently pointing to android-10. You can find more information on this file and others [here](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/index.html).